# Hikvision API retrieve events, people counting camera

Tags: c#, api, isapi, hikvision

I am trying to get event details from a Hikvision People Counting Camera, e.g. enter event. The model is:: iDS-2CD6810F/C Firmware:: V5.4.7 build 171115. I am using postman to try and connect to the API but I am getting nowhere. No matter what configuration of query string I use it is getting Unauthorized error, even when trying to log in. This is not so much a specific question on how to fix something but I was wondering has anyone got an example query string used to log in to this camera or even retrieving the events?

Response from Camera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Document Error: Unauthorized</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Access Error: 401 -- Unauthorized</h2>
    <p>Authentication Error</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to be authorized. HikVision is chinese hardware, but not THAT insecure :)
You need to add basic or digest (that depends on camera and its security settings) authorization header to your HTTP request using same admin login/password you're using for web interface (or other user if you created it)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your username and password admin from the device to youre request url
something like this.

http://[admin usr]:[PWD]@YOURDEVICEIP/
http://admin:Kusnj&4@10.65.87.6/ISAPI/Thermal/channels/[ID]/thermometry/

Answer (score 0):

In order to authorize to HikVision camera using Postman you need to enter "Authorization" tab, choose the "Digest Auth" Type and enter username and password as shown below ;)

[image]