# How can I get Events from Hikvision camera to my Typescript project and is there any documentation on the camera's internal API?

Tags: webhooks, ip-camera, isapi, hikvision

I have a project where I need to get events from the Hikvision camera that I've connected on my network, to my Typescript project's code.

The events in question are **face detection** and **alarm triggered by recognized face**.

The events then would go through webhook in the code and call corresponding functions to send the information to my front-end application.

---

I know there is an internal API (actually ISAPI) built into the camera, and I know that there are at least 2 endpoints called:

`/ISAPI/Intelligent/`

and

`/ISAPI/Event/`

There surely are lots of different endpoints under there.

---

However, I can't find any documentation for this API / ISAPI even from Hikvision's product support website.

There 3 PDF-manuals on the [product support page](https://www.hikvision.com/europe/products/IP-Products/Network-Cameras/DeepinView-Series/ids-2cd8146g0-izs/?q=ids-2cd8146g0-izs&position=17) and none of them mention API or endpoints.

Are there any documentation of these API endpoints for Hikvision cameras?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332574/hikvision-api-retrieve-events-people-counting-camera) does not solve my case (I already know how to authenticate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out you can setup a webhook on your Express server app and point the camera's http-listening towards the app's webhook endpoint.

The http-listening is done from the camera's internal software that lives at the camera's IP-address.